# Angular service worker won't cache base-href files angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

with basic base-href set to "/" caching and offline capabilities work fine. but i add base-href as /gpcalc, service worker works fine but wont cache anything apart from the favicon.

I can't post all the codes but i made sure i added the prefixs to the necessary places

angular.json

```
        "scripts": [],
        "baseHref": "/gpcalc",
        "deployUrl": "/gpcalc/"
      },
```

ngsw.json

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "index": "/gpcalc/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/gpcalc/favicon.ico",
        "/gpcalc/index.html",
        "/gpcalc/main.d7aef1b275e860c047e2.js",
        "/gpcalc/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js",
        "/gpcalc/runtime.6a6469df6f05f1e96e63.js",
        "/gpcalc/styles.00215c918d545884d4b5.css"
      ],
      "patterns": []
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GpCalc</title>
  <base href="/gpcalc">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/gpcalc/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/gpcalc/assets/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/gpcalc/assets/css/animate.css">

  <link rel="manifest" href="/gpcalc/manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/gpcalc/styles.00215c918d545884d4b5.css"></head>
```

app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/gpcalc/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
  ],
```